# Ordenar y filtrar

Tags: rstudio

Tengo un problema en R que, ojalá me puedan ayudar

Tengo una serie de data.frame con la siguiente estructura:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | do | X | X | X |
| 2 | do | X | X | X |
| 6 | do | X | X | X |
| 5 | re | X | X | X |
| 4 | re | X | X | X |
| 9 | do | X | X | X |
| 11 | mi | X | X | X |
| 4 | sol | X | X | X |
| 6 | sol | X | X | X |

Busco que me queden los mayores valores de B, en función de A.
Es decir

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | re | X | X | X |
| 9 | do | X | X | X |
| 11 | mi | X | X | X |
| 6 | sol | X | X | X |

Nota: son 15.000 datos

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega lo que has realizado, revisar [ask], saludos